# Webkit isn't loading a long JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, webkit

I'm having issues where both Chrome and Safari aren't loading all my JavaScript. My file is rather large uncompressed, 16000+ lines, but it's working fine in Firefox and Opera. I'm using Mac as well and haven't tested Windows yet.

Does anyone know if Webkit clips a file after a certain line number?

Comment: If you browse the script from the development tools window, does it show all lines of the script?

Answer (score 2):

I have a few files that are about that long and don't have problems with any web kit browsers. 
Are you using any debug tools to see if any errors are being generated?

In chrome you can press ctrl+shift+I and get a developer tools console that could help with things.

Comment: I have the console and it's not showing anything. No errors and my `console.log()` isn't displaying. I know code from the file is running, but it's stopping somewhere and I can't tell where.

Comment: Best I could tell you at this point would be to put in console.logs in several places from start to finish, this way you could tell which one's it is getting to and which ones it isn't.

Comment: It was unrelated. For some reason Chrome wasn't reporting the syntax error with an unrelated function and Firefox 6 was allowing it. Testers with FF4/5 were seeing the error just fine.

Comment: Funny, I had a similar issue with Chrome and PLUpload, had to install firebug light on users Chrome to get PLUpload to work - otherwise it would just hang without errors. Ended up being how Chrome changed how Blobs are handled, and Firebug made it handle them differently or something like that.